# Is iOS app Launch Screen (splash screen) a must?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile-application, mobile-development

Based on the following article

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

having a launch screen aka splash screen is a must for ios app when developing. but I realised many apps such as facebook or twiter does not have any launch screen on iPhone.

I have tried removing the LaunchScreen.xib from my project on XCode (8) but I get build fail error.

Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: The main idea behind splash screen is to give users of your app an appearance of an immediate start. Some apps have splash screen that looks like their initial screen. I think Apple wants you to have a launch screen, and I am not sure if they would let your app into app store without it.

Comment: Facebook and Twitter do have launch screens, they just look like an empty app, but they do use them.

Comment: If I make my launch screen "almost identical to the first screen" users will just poke at the button and never get a response. I don't understand the purpose of the launch screen other than to make users angry.

Comment: So, looking at real apps from the app store I realized NO ONE follows apple's official advice to make the launch screen look almost the same as the first screen. Figures... I don't understand why that would be a good idea. What is so good about making a user mad that expected ui elements don't respond.

Comment: In the guidelines it is mentioned to make the launch screen look almost the same as the first screen by adding only the static and non interactive components of first screen to the launch screen. This is to give user a smooth transitioning experience from launch screen to your app's first screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have storyboard or Launch Image.You can remove *LaunchScreen.xib*, but you have to add *Launch Images*. For using Launch Images you can try [rn-splash-screen](https://github.com/mehcode/rn-splash-screen).

Answer (score 3):

You must have a launch screen. The reason it appears that some apps do not is that they make their launch screen look the same as the first screen that displays after launch is completed.

Answer (score 3):

An iOS app must have a splash screen according to Apple documentation. Without a splash screen, Apple will reject your app. But you if removed the launch screen from your project, it will not crash when you change launch screen file as in image.

[image]